# How to dynamically decide if a request should go thru a middleware in Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

All:

I am pretty new to Epxress, I build a middleware to check user credential, and I specify it like:

```
var check = function(req, res, next){/* checking user cred*/}
```

And I use it like:

```
app.use(check);
```

OR like:

```
app.get("some url", check, function(req, res, next){})
```

But there is only one thing confuses me, sometimes, I need to skip the check in same handler depends on req.query, **I wonder if there is a way(or design pattern) to do this without specify this condition checking inside check middleware( I just want to make check modulized and focus on its biz logic)?**

Thanks

Comment: are you saying you want to avoid doing condition checking inside the check middleware?

Comment: @markthethomas Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authentication, a typical pattern would be to have a collection of routes that allow anonymous access, and a section that requires authentication, thus calls your middleware.

Additionally, look into the Passport library for your authentication concerns, it integrates really well into express.

Comment: Thanks, I tried passport before, but it seems a little hard to me to understand at that time, so switch to Web Token way, but I will give it another try this time.

Comment: For future users looking to figure out how they can use JWT, I don't think the accepted answer should be "use passport instead" :)

Comment: The poster wasn't explicit in his technology choice. I'm sure there is a pattern or library for JWT that doesn't involve hand rolling your own authentication :). Besides, if the app is structured correctly, there shouldn't be a need to conditionally apply authentication middle ware.

Comment: Additionally, there appear to be several JWT strategies for Passport on npm

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to modularize the check middleware so you can use it elsewhere, you could pretty easily include some sort of flag to check against the `req.query` parameter or whatever else you'd want to check and make it more generic:

```
function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.query){
  //   do some kind of check
  } else {
  // do a check with req.query
  }
}
```

Is that along the lines of what you are trying to do?